# get "clear is not a function" from console on chrome dev tool

Tags: javascript, google-developers-console

I hope anyone could help me understand this situation.
So, I wanted to clear the console after trying some simple codes like...

```
const smt = {printThis(){console.log(this)}};
smt.printThis();
```

and then typed clear as always, to clear it.

But then got this error saying clear is not a function.
And when typed clear and pressed enter, it shows  tag.  ...?

I really want to know what this is about, and hopefully, someone knows about it.
Just in case it's already been asked here, really sorry if my searching wasn't enough.

[image: clearIsNotAFunction]

Comment: have you tried `console.clear()`?

Comment: because clear isn't a native method in javascript. you can just hold ctrl+L to clear the console.

Comment: you could try console.clear() https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_clear.asp

Comment: Can't recreate the same conditions here with the information provided. This is the only code you run before getting the error?

Comment: @Undo, Rogelio
Thank you for your comments. I did try console.clear() before I asked this question. and yes it works haha. I was just curious to know why clear(); wouldn't work though.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida 
Hi, Ed. I just found out that this would only happen in the dev tool of a tab that opened youtube website.
Without running any other codes, clear() gives me 'clear is not a function' error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On that page, as you show, there is an element with `id="clear"`. Elements with `id`s automatically create global variables pointing to them with the name of that variable being that `id`, so `clear()` in your console is trying to **run** the element, which leads to your error.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes or in some browser or some window clear function doesn't work . If is gives an error , try console.clear();

Answer (score -1):

console.clear();
hope it will work. happy coding.

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new details. If this is the case here, please add some explanation to your answer, such that others can learn from it